# I'm running a Rails 2.3.4 app and am wondering if i should upgrade to 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

i am developing a app and have been for a while using Rails 2.3.4
 but I'm wondering if i should try to update, or keep waiting, never upgrade, i suppose I have a couple options.

I am using ruby 1.8.7 would i need to upgrade that too huh?

how difficult would this be/ how much code would this break, would i have lots of unexpected results?

any input would be appreciated, I'm somewhat lost.

Comment: You've looked over this already? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html

Comment: Just curious.  Did you consider a less drastic upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 2.4.0 ?

Comment: i have not looked at that, and no but is suppose i could..but if im going to go through the trouble why not go all they way..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It largely depends on your constraints. If you plan on keeping the site up and running, and it has significant importance to you and/or your client, then staying on the Rails "golden path" is worth it. In general, upgrading Rails 2 to Rails 3 is relatively easy.

You may want to check to see if your plugins / gems are Rails 3 compatible at http://www.railsplugins.org/.

In terms of learning curve, you'll want to get familiar with bundler.

You can stick with Ruby 1.8.7.

Now, if you want to embrace all the advantages of Rails 3, that will take a little more time (refactoring) but it shouldn't stop you from upgrading.

For more information you might take a look at: http://www.railsupgradehandbook.com/